SignalR React - transport disabled by client
I want to implement a SignalR Client in react.
I have an aspnet API which provides SignalR Hub. With a C# SignalR Client I can connect with the hub and send+ receive messages. So it seems that the SignalR Service and CORS are correct.
But when I want to connect with react I get following error:
Debug: HubConnection failed to start successfully because of error 'Error: Unable to connect 
to the server with any of the available transports.
WebSockets failed: 
Error: 'WebSockets' is disabled by the client.
ServerSentEvents failed: Error: 'ServerSentEvents' is disabled by the client.
LongPolling failed: Error: 'LongPolling' is disabled by the client.'.

My react code:
import { HubConnectionBuilder,LogLevel,HttpTransportType } from '@microsoft/signalr';
import { getUserAccessToken } from '../auth/UserManager';

export function ConnectToSignalR(){
   return  new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('http://localhost:18198/messagehub',options=> {
            options.skipNegotiation=false;
            options.transport = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
            options.accessTokenFactory = ()=>getUserAccessToken();
        return options;})
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Trace)
        .build();
}

export function startSignalRConnection(signalRConnection){
    if (signalRConnection) {
        signalRConnection.start()
              .then(result => {
                  console.log('SingnalR','Connected!');
    
                  signalRConnection.on('TimeWarningMessage', message => {
                     console.log(message);
                  });
              })
              .catch(e => console.log('SingalR Connection failed: ', e));
            }
        
}

Code is called in App.js (main component) of react app via useEffect hook once application starts.
What is meant by 'is disabled by the client'?
Is there a way those things can be disabled?
Browser I tested is current version of Edge and Chrome, both have same issue.
Version of react package is 8.0.7 and in Backend on asp net core side, I am using NET8

Could you share me the code about JwtBearerEvents ? Becasue this block was missing also will face this error.

It isn't about JWTBearer, even if i completly remove Authentication in Backend Hub, the error even exists. I just found out, my options are incorrect. See my new post for solution.

I just found out, that my options were incorrect.
If i use another example from the internet it works.
See:
export function ConnectToSingalR(){
   return  new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('http://localhost:18198/messagehub', {
            accessTokenFactory: () => {              
                return getUserAccessToken();
            }
        })
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Trace)
        .build();
}

But I dont understand why the option part produces this error. If it is not correct ok, my fault but i just expected a better and understandable error message....
